# How can I solve for $x\,$? $:\;\;x-x_r=(x-x_1)e^{\large -(x-x_1)^2}$

Tags: numerical-methods, problem-solving

I want to find $x$ for given values of $x_r$ and $x_1\,$ (domain $\mathbb{R}$):

$$x-x_r=(x-x_1)e^{\large -(x-x_1)^2}$$

Thanks

Comment: I think you will have to content yourself with a numerical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the equation as ${{x-x_r}\over{x-x_1}}=e^{-(x-x_1)^2}$ and graph each side. The left is a hyperbola with a vertical asymptote at $x=x_1$ and a horizontal one at $y=1$. The right side is a bell shaped curve with max at $(x_1,1)$. Now decide based on $x_r>x_1$ or $x_r<x_1$ to see where the unique root is going to be. Next you my try to get some asymptotics of the answer. It all depends.

Comment: How can I solve it numerically (approximately), for example can I use e^-(x^2) expansion.

Comment: Do you know [Newton-Raphson mathod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)? This is a numerical method where you start with an initial guess and improve it through iterations. You need to take derivatives to use this. There is also [fixed-point iteration method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_iteration) which is simpler but slower. You typically need numbers for $x_1$ and $x_r$ at the start.

Comment: You will have an easier time if you change your variables. Let $x=x_r+y$ and $a=x_r-x_1$ then your equation becomes $y=(y+a)e^{-(y+a)^2}$. Now you have just one parameter to worry about namely $a$.

Comment: $y$ becomes an odd function of $a$ meaning if you change sign of $a$ then sign of $y$ will also change. So you can concentrate on positive $a$'s. Many software or online pages/apps solve this type of equation for you. In Maple you can use:       for i from 0 by .1 to 4 do z := fsolve(x-(x+i)*exp(-(x+i)^2) = 0, x); print(i, z) end do; to get
 0.1, 0.3821323792; 0.2, 0.4225239009; 0.3, 0.4284936468;
 0.4, 0.4188046129; 0.5, 0.4002917456; 0.6, 0.3763617819;
 0.7, 0.3490298472; 0.8, 0.3196340536; and so on.

Comment: Do you think if I can expand e^-(x^2) up to for example x^4 and solve it analytically? I tested it in mathematica, but the solution was very long and I'm not sure if it can be precise enough.

Comment: Let me think about it. There is a catch 22 in such problems. The style of expansion should match the solution for it to be useful but then you need to know the solution. To see the curve of solution you can go to [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com) and simply type `solve y=(y+a)*e^(-(y+a)^2) for y in terms of a` to see what you are trying to capture. You see a rapid rise to about y=0.4 at about a=0.3 and then a tail. This suggests the types of functions to be used to approximate the solution analytically. Your final approximate solution $y=f(a)$ should have similar characteristics.

Comment: Yes that expansion does provide useful answer. For the first attempt I get $y\approx a^{1/3}$ which seems to agree with numerical answers for very small values of $a$. For example for $a=0.004$, $y=.1554124270$, while $a^{1/3}=.158$.

Comment: For large values of $a$ you can get $y\approx a e^{-a^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am trying other approx, because its likely there must be a more global one (in my application, a is in [0.001-0.5]).

Comment: I was wondering about the origin of this question. I want to assign it as a project to some students and it would be nice to to have some background material and justification of why the problem has significance.

Comment: I'm 3rd year PhD student in computer science. I am working on privacy and security in DB. One approach to preserve the privacy is to group some data records into similar clusters and publish the centroid instead of the original data. The centroid can bee seen as a simple mathematical average (the whole method is called microaggregation) which is a hot research area in the field. It is interesting to publish as a centroid the point which is near to the regular center (math average), while it is far enough from the real data points. Solving the equation reduces to the problem above (very simple)

Comment: A student of mine did some work on this problem. If interested let me know how he can contact you.

Comment: hi, of course, I'm not sure if I can put my email here, so I suggest to post here (it may be interesting for others), if there exists any problem, let me know send you my email!

Comment: Thanks, send email to  m a e s u m i at math dot lamar dot edu then  I arrange from there.